# Manual Acknowledge (commit) kafka messages with ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using ReplyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive() to send and receive a message correlated by correlation id.
The use case have many topics on the way, and I need to manual acknoledge (commit) consumed messages offsets. So far so good, this is done using:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.request-topic}")
    @SendTo("int1")
    public Tx30 listen(@Payload Tx30 request, Acknowledgment ack) throws InterruptedException {
        ...
        ack.acknowledge();
```

But I don´t know how to manual acknoledge the last message (the one consumed by sendAndReceive().

Any hint how to do that?

Thanks

Fernando

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no support for manually committing the offset for a reply message.

If you can explain a valid use case for why that might be needed, feel free to open a new feature request issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues).